# Angularjs - Field mandatory if condition

Tags: angularjs

i am using angular-messages.min.js for the validations.

I have the next web form:

```
<form role="form" name="form">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                <label class="control-label">Field1</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="field1" ng-model="field1" ng-options="item for item in device" ng-change="deviceChange();"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
                <label class="control-label">Field2</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="field2" ng-model="field2" ng-options="item for item in use"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.field1.$invalid && form.field2.$invalid }">
                <label class="control-label">Field3</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field3" ng-model="field3" />
                <div class="help-block" ng-messages="form.field3.$error" ng-if="form.field3.$touched">
                    <p ng-message="required">Your field3 is required</p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The fields, field1, field2 and field3 are not mandatory, but if the field1 and field2 has content, the field3 is mandatory.

How could to show the validation message in field3? thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field3" ng-required="field1 && field2" ng-model="field3" />
```